# MySQL HAVING function

Tags: php, mysql, having, having-clause

I have an SQL command that have the following line in it,

```
HAVING
   DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, '%Y')
   - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d')
   < DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, '00-%m-%d')) <= ". $v
```

`$v` is a PHP variable that is an integer multiplying in multiples of 10. Instead of looking for all entries that have a DOB of below $v I am wanting to return all the entries that have a DOB of less then than `$v` but great than `$v - 10` is that possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understood your question, but wouldn't `"HAVING DATE_FORMAT(candidates.DOB, '%Y') BETWEEN {$v-10} AND {$v}"` do?

Comment: Do you need to use HAVING for this? You could probably just do this in the WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the having statement to select clause, assign it an alias (say calculatedValue) and use the alias in the having clause. Final SQL query will be like:

```
  select 
      DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, '00-%m-%d')) calculatedValue
  from 
    candidates 
  having 
    calculatedValue <= 15 and calculatedValue > 5
```

You have to modify it a bit to use inside php script. I did the formatting but then it was less readable.